# Spiderman comment question

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, avengers-infinity-war

So I was watching *Avengers: Infinity War* after I saw *Endgame* and when 2 of the Black Order members (Ebony Maw and Black Dwarf) were fighting against Iron Man, Spider-man came for help.

Tony Stark asked

> Kid where did you come from?

Spider-man answered

> Future.

So I was thinking, Does it mean anything?

EDIT: I was wrong sipderman says :

> Field Trip

Thanks to @Paulie_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You misheard

The actual dialogue is

> Tony Stark: Kid, where'd you come from?
>
> Peter Parker: Field trip to MoMA. *(Museum of Modern Art)*

Comment: I Just re-watched that part and noticed that, thanks.

Comment: But MoMA *is* the future!